# switched from linux to mac and rake db:migrate now fails because config/database.yml doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-lion

Backstory - I bought a new MacBook Air before Christmas and then went on vacation with it. I left my POS 10 year old linux laptop that I've been using for rails development at home. When I got back, some retarded burglar had stolen my linux laptop. You can literally buy that model for $25 on ebay. Anyway, I was hoping for a nice slow migration over to my new MacBook but I've been forced to get this up and running ASAP.

The problem I'm having now is that I've cloned a project that I was working on - thank you github - but something funny's going on. When I try to setup the database `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /Users/spinlock/rails/AtomicBroadcast/config/database.yml

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea what's going on here? I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.1. I'm completely new to the Mac environment so I might be making a stupid mistake so please don't assume I know anything :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `database.yml` file?

Comment: isn't your database.yml file in .gitignore? if it is ... it wont be cloned :)

Comment: I think this is my problem. I've never had to worry about the database.yml file before. I put one in the local directory and now everything works. I just need to read the docs to figure out what this does.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely nothing Mac specific.

Darwin, Mac's kernel is a lot like FreeBSD.

Most of your linux commands are available through Terminal.

ls, cat, file etc.. should all return something about the file if it exists but, the only thing that would cause that error is for the file to simply be missing in that path.

If you can find the file in Finder, a cool trick is to drag the file into the Terminal window where it will output the actual path.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of the OP not understanding that OS X is Unixy.

Comment: I agree but assuming a Linux user going to Mac knows nothing about the new platform a "treat it just like linux" statement is in order.